# Sorting elements of a tie

Tags: r

Given this table

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c(letters[3:5], "b","a"),
                 col2 = c(2:3, 1,1,1))
```

How can I tell R to return "a". 
That means, from the three characters with value of 1 (a tie for the lowest value), I want to select only the first in alphabetical order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want `order`

```
with(df, col1[order(col2, col1)][1])
# [1] a
# Levels: a b c d e
```

or

```
as.character(with(df, col1[order(col2, col1)][1]))
# [1] "a"
```

You can order column 1 by the ordered values in column 2 with

```
df[with(df, order(col2, col1)),]
#   col1 col2
# 5    a    1
# 4    b    1
# 3    e    1
# 1    c    2
# 2    d    3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
> min(as.character(df[df$col2==min(df$col2),1]))
[1] "a"
```

For explanation:

```
# first find col1 list in rows with minimum of df$col2
> xx = df[df$col2==min(df$col2),1]
> xx
[1] e b a
Levels: a b c d e

# Now find the minimum amongst these after converting factor to character: 
> min(as.character(xx))
[1] "a"
>
```